# google play store licensing check -- new app

Tags: android, google-play

I gather from other postings that it is near impossible to my check licensing code until i publish a new app for the first time in the google play store?

I have uploaded my apk to the Play dev console, (promoted to prod, but unpublished), tested with account owner ID, and still come up with "ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED" as the license response.

If true what is a good strategy for not making it available to anyone else who might purchase and then complain that it fails licensing checks before i test licensing and fix any related coding problems?   Can I make it available in "no countries" at first?    Should I put a ridiculously high price in a single country (and does that have to include my own country)?

I would hope there are better solutions to this dilema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using [Google Play Licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/overview.html), they write:

> Note: Previously you could test an app by uploading an unpublished "draft" version. This functionality is no longer supported; instead, you must publish it to the alpha or beta distribution channel. For more information, see [Draft Apps are No Longer Supported](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#draft_apps).

Comment: Ah, so a PUBLISHED app with no production apk (alpha/bets apk only) will not make it possible for premature purchase.  There's always these undocumented bits that make for a guessing game.  Thanks for your reply!